# Example of differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Can you give an example of differential equation $F(t, x, x')$ which is defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^3$, but there is no solution which is defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$. I tried to think about the answer, however, all my examples has solution $x = 0$ or something like this, which violates condition, because such functions are defined everewhere on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $x' = 1+x^2$, $y'=z'= 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Was just about to post that as an answer. Why didn't you?

Comment: @Arthur: By all means, go ahead :-). I am about to go to sleep and will almost surely make some wine induced mistakes...

Comment: @copper.hat I think we both made one: This question looks like it's about second-order equations.

Comment: @Arthur It seems, that $x' = 1 + x^2$ is OK, isn't it?